# C# game ticking with delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm working on a game that does things when the tick is 'x'. I have a TickEvent delegate that is a method what runs when it has to.

```
public delegate void TickEvent(object[] objects);
```

I have a scheduler that runs the method at a specific tick.

```
public static void scheduleTick(long tick, TickEvent tickEvent)
    {
        queue.put(tick, tickEvent);
    }
```

And a handler.

```
public static void handleScheduledTicks()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < queue.variables.Count; i++)
            {
                if((long)queue.variables[i] < elapsedTicks)
                {
                    var tickEvent = (TickEvent)queue.values[i];
                    // runs the tickEvent with its arguments

                    queue.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

Making the event:

```
public static void someEvent(object[] objects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(objects[0].ToString());
}

Calling the eventHandler and scheduling the event:

    static long ticks = 0;

    public static void Main()
    {
        scheduleTick(100, someEvent(new object[]() {"some args"})

        while(true)
        {
            handleScheduledTicks();
            ticks++;
        }
    }
```

So my question is how can I run the tickEvent with its arguments? (handleScheduledTicks commented line)

Answer (score 0):

I feel something wrong with below line itself :

```
public static void Main()
    {
        scheduleTick(100, someEvent(new object[]() {"some args"})
        /* this will not complile. you are passing `void` to method `handleScheduledTicks` as an argument to type of TickEvent. It should be like :
           scheduleTick(100, someEvent) */

        while(true)
        {
            handleScheduledTicks();
            ticks++;
        }
    }
```

And `handleScheduledTicks` part should be :

```
if((long)queue.variables[i] < elapsedTicks)
                {
                    var tickEvent = (TickEvent)queue.values[i];
                    /* tickEvent(new object[]() {"some args"}); */
                    queue.remove(i);
                }
```

Comment: How do I know in the handleScheduledTicks what the tickEvent's arguments are?

Comment: you should pass that as an argument to 'handleScheduledTicks' method.

Comment: Is there any other ways? Because the tickEvent's argument not always the same, and the handleScheduleTicks don't know what the arguments are. So if no other ways how would you do that, to schedule a method with any arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution:

```
tickEvent(tickEvent.Method.GetParameters());
```